# recvfrom not receiving depending on ai_family used

Tags: c, sockets, localhost

I'm trying to get my head around socket programming and have encountered some unexpected (for me) behaviour.

When I try to send data to "localhost" and set addrinfo.ai_family to AF_INET the message I send isn't coming through from my client process to my host process (recvfrom() doesn't return). If I set it to AF_INET6 all is fine. Same for AF_UNSPEC in which case it picks the IPv6 addrinfo (first in the list). Both host and client use the same ai_family of course.

I've also tried this with code copy pasted from [beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) which had the same result. I'm using DGRAM sockets.

I tried connecting from a different pc I got the opposite results, IPv4 worked fine, IPv6 did not. I gather this may be due to me using a '6to4 gateway'. I really have no idea what this means.

The problem is related to my own machine as the code does work over IPv4 on another machine I tested it on.
I can't say if it's a sending or receiving problem.

What could prevent me from sending or receiving data to/from localhost using AF_INET sockets?

I'm on a windows7 64bit machine compiling with MingW.
If it makes any difference I'm running the same program for host and client processes with different arguments. I ran the release and debug programs together (so it's not the same program twice) but got the same results.

Thanks in advance and apologies if this is considered a stupid question.

code:

```
typedef struct addrinfo addrinfo_t;
typedef struct sockaddr_storage sockaddr_storage_t;
typedef struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_in_t;
typedef struct sockaddr_in6 sockaddr_in6_t;

void connect_to_server(const char* server_name, const char* message)
{
    int status;
    init_networking();
    addrinfo_t hints;
    addrinfo_t* res;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(addrinfo_t));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; //or AF_INET6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    if ((status = getaddrinfo(server_name, "4950", &hints, &res)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }
    SOCKET s = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (s == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not create a socket, errno: %u\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    int bytes_sent = sendto(s, message, strlen(message), 0, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    close(s);
    printf("Sent %i bytes to port %i\n", bytes_sent, ((sockaddr_in_t*)res->ai_addr)->sin_port);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
}

void setup_server()
{
    int status;
    init_networking();
    addrinfo_t hints;
    addrinfo_t* res;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(addrinfo_t));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; //or AF_INET6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, "4950", &hints, &res)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKET s = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (s == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not create a socket, errno: %u\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    //Bind the socket to own address (mostly the port number contained in the address)
    if (bind(s, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to bind, errno: %u\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    const size_t read_buffer_size = 1024;
    void* read_buffer = malloc(read_buffer_size);

    sockaddr_storage_t peer_address;
    int peer_address_length = sizeof(sockaddr_storage_t);

    sockaddr_storage_t own_sock_addr;
    int own_sock_addr_len = sizeof(sockaddr_storage_t);
    getsockname(s, (struct sockaddr*)&own_sock_addr, &own_sock_addr_len);
    printf("Listening on port %i\n", ((sockaddr_in_t*)&own_sock_addr)->sin_port);

    int bytes_received = recvfrom(s,
                                read_buffer,
                                read_buffer_size-1,
                                0,
                                (struct sockaddr*)&peer_address,
                                &peer_address_length                    );

    printf("Received %i byte message:\n%s\n", bytes_received, (char*)read_buffer);
}
```

Comment: I can think of several different reasons this might happen, ranging from subtle bugs in your code to a misconfigured loopback interface on the computer where you tried it.  We're going to need to see the code.  Also, try running the same program on a different physical computer.

Comment: I used code copied from a guide with the same results as my own code so I thought that wouldn't be the problem. Added it now. AF_INET with localhost did indeed work on another machine I tested it on just now (good idea). I am a bit more concerned about AF_INET6 not working on remote connections though.

Comment: If the same code works on another machine, we're probably looking at a system configuration problem on the machine where it doesn't work.  Since this is Windows, I can't help you with that.

Comment: Yes looks like it. I also apparently have no internet access over IPv6, so that's likely the problem. Still haven't had much luck finding how to fix it though.

Answer (score 2):

`AF_INET` is for IPv4, and `AF_INET6` is for IPv6.  When sending an IPv4 datagram, the receiver must be receiving data on the destination IP/port using either an IPv4 socket or an [IPv6 dual stack socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513665.aspx) (an IPv6 socket that accepts both IPv4 and IPv6 traffic).  When sending an IPv6 datagram, the receiver must be receiving data using an IPv6 socket.  Otherwise, the datagram will be ignored,  So it sounds like the one machine is using an IPv6 socket that ignores your IPv4 datagram, and the other machine is using an IPv4 socket that ignores your IPv6 datagram.

When you are calling `getaddrinfo()`, you are specifying `AF_UNSPEC` as the address family in both client and server.  `AF_UNSPEC` tells `getaddrinfo()` that you want both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, so it returns a **linked list** that potentially contains **multiple** entries for all of the available IPv4 **and** IPv6 addresses.  On the server side, you are creating a single listening socket for only the first entry in the list, which may be IPv4 or IPv6.  On the client side, you are creating a single sending socket for only the first entry in the list, which may be IPv4 or IPv6.  So the actual address families used in both operations are going to be random and may mismatch each other at times.

On the server side, you need to either:

1. use `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` directly, instead of `AF_UNSPEC`, and then code the client accordingly to match.
2. loop through the entire `addrinfo` list creating a separate listening socket for every entry. That way, clients can send data to any IP/Port family the server is listening on.
3. use `AF_INET6` only when creating the listening socket(s), but then enable [dual stack functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513665.aspx) on them (Vista+ only) so they can receive both IPv4 and IPv6 datagrams.  You will then have to pay attention to the address family reported by the `sockaddr` that `recvfrom()` returns in order to know whether any given datagram is using IPv4 or IPv6.

On the client side, you need to use `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` directly, instead of `AF_UNSPEC`, depending on what the server is actually listening on.  It does not make sense to use `AF_UNSPEC` for a UDP client socket (it does make sense for a TCP client socket), unless the UDP protocol you are implementing replies to each datagram with an ack.  Without that, the client has no way to know whether the server is accepting IPv4 or IPv6 datagrams (unless the user tells the app).  With acks, the client could loop through the returned `addrinfo` list, sending a datagram to an entry in the list, wait a few seconds for an ack, and if not received then move on to the next entry in the list, repeating as needed until an ack actually arrives or the list is exhausted.

Comment: I'm constantly changing the values manually to test things (making sure the values are the same for client and server). They just happenned to be AF_UNSPEC the last time I ran the code.
EDIT: changed the code to fix mix-up.

Comment: My comment about creating a separate listening socket for each entry in the `addrinfo` list still stands. Also, `sin_port` is in network byte order so use `ntohs()` when logging it. And you need better error handling on your `sendto()` and `recvto()` calls. Outside of that, if you are still having problems, then use Wireshark or other packet sniffer to make sure the datagrams are actually being transmitted and received on each end and are using the expected address families.